# WPF Databind a class with a List

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a presentation class as contain a List of an other class. How can I show the content of the List class in WPF DataGrid?

```
namespace AktieAnalyse.TekniskAnalyse.RSI
{
  public class RSI
  {
    public decimal xAntalDageRsi { get; set; }
    public decimal NiDagesRsi { get; set; }
    public decimal FjortenDagesRsi { get; set; }
    public decimal NiogfyrreDagesRsi { get; set; }
    public decimal EthundreogHalvtressDagesRsi { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace AktieAnalyseWPFUserControls.View.Presentation
{
  public class RSI
  {
    public int IdVirksomhedensStamdata { get; set; }
    public string VirksomhedensNavn { get; set; }

    public List<AktieAnalyse.TekniskAnalyse.RSI.RSI> RsiListe { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In WPF the 'VirksomhedsNavn' works correct, but not 'RsiListe.NiDagesRsi':

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Rsi" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Virksomhedsnavn" Binding="{Binding Path=VirksomhedensNavn}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RSI 9" Binding="{Binding Path=RsiListe.NiDagesRsi}">
```

If I tried this:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RSI 9" Binding="{Binding Path=RsiListe[0].NiDagesRsi}">
```

It works (of course only on the first row). How can I get it to work on all rows?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your viewmodel is the class of type RSI? Try following.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Rsi" ItemsSource="{Binding RsiListe}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="RSI 9" Binding="{Binding Path=NiDagesRsi}">
```

Also can you explain why you want to bind to the datagrid from your viewmodel and the list? Also might be a good idea to not have two classes named RSI and if its acronym might be good idea to write it verbose mode.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest binding the list to an `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than a list.

This implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` internally, so when you set the contents of the list, it will update the GUI.